# How can I access a service in config function or access a provider inside a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I need to configure **angular bootstrap tooltip (uibTooltip)** to be disabled for mobile devices when using  [`angular-bowser`](https://github.com/jacqueslareau/angular-bowser) for device detection.

This could be done simply by:

```
isMobile = _bowser.mobile
$uibTooltipProvider.options = { trigger: isMobile ? "none" : "mouseenter" }
```

**Problem:** `$uibTooltipProvider` is a **provider** and `bowser` is a **service**.

I have to use `$uibTooltipProvider` in a `config` function while I can't use `bowser` service in a `config` function. And neither I can use `$uibTooltipProvider` in a `run` function where I can use `bowser`

I have already tried overriding the $get function as they suggest [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2525) but the **"ontouchstart"** event in $window does not apply for tablets where I want to keep tooltips enabled.

Is there any way I can get a workaround this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally decided to inject a small css modification in run time. I had the three following options:

**1.** Use that [hack on GitHub](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2525): I did not like the fact that in order to make it work I had to empirically (by placing a breaking point) find out which were the actual services injected in the $get function of the uibTooltipProvider. (see there is a difference between the services injected in the github thread and the ones I had to inject [(see code snippet)](https://gist.github.com/Totemika/0c240641c05c16f4cc944386e2766256)

**2.** Add the bowser library and use it statically: I did not like this option because we are already using angular-bowser as a dependency for our DeviceDetector service, so we would be using the same library twice: one statically to configure the tooltip options and one in runtime for everything else.

**3.** Inject a small css modification (the option I chose):

`public disableTooltipsForTouchScreen(): void {
      if ( this._deviceDetector.isMobile() || this._deviceDetector.isTablet() )    {
        let styleSheet = document.createElement("style");
        styleSheet["innerHTML"] = ".tooltip { display: none; }";
        document.body.appendChild(styleSheet);
      }
    }`

And if we ever need to have a finest control over the bootstrap-tooltip configuration then I will consider option 2.